# Background position on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a link (a balise) and I try to put a background-image position as an icon to it so I do like in this snippet :

```css
.page {
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 850px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.page ul.col-2 {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
    background-color: #f49841;
}

.page ul.col-2 li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li {
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #4286f4;
  height: 30%;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li:nth-child(2) {
  height: 70%;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li ul.col-2 {
  padding: 0;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li ul.col-2 li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li ul.col-2 li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #40ed48;
}

.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li ul.col-2 li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ed3f3f;
}


.page ul.col-2 li ul.line-2 li .my-link {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Deletion_icon.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<ul class="col-2">
 <li>
   <div class="text-1">
     text 1
   </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <ul class="line-2">
   <li>
    <div class="box-text">
     <a class="my-link">My link</a>
    </div>
   </li>
    <li>
    <ul class="col-2">
     <li>
      text 2
      
     </li>
     <li>
      text 3
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It's work everywhere except on IE. I try to change the position or display. But nothing gives the result I expect.

=== EDIT ===

I just check and weirdly it' s look like it' s working inside the snippet.

I join a picture of my code

[image: code]

== EDIT 2 ==

I update my snippet code to give a better view of what is around the link but still give a good result. I join a picture of what appears on my env : 
[image]

It just looks like the background-position is always center no matter the value I put.

Comment: Inspect the element for the one that doesn't work and ensure all syles have been copied into the snippet - there's obviously something you have missed

Comment: I check but there is no difference. The difference is that the link element is inside other div I'm trying to prepare another snippet but until now the result in the snippet is always good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move delete icon css to `:after` element and it works fine **IE11**. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.my-link {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .my-link:after {
      background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Deletion_icon.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: right;
      padding-right: 30px;
      content: '';
    }

.my-link:hover {
  color: red;
}

.my-link:hover::after {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/warnings-and-dangers/400/Warning-02-512.png);
}
```

```html
<a class="my-link">My link</a>
```

Comment: The problem is that on the hover I wanna change the picture and the color of the text.

Comment: Can you please clear the confusion that whether you have issue with background position or you have any issue with color and image change on hover? It is better if you inform all your issues in the original post may help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I just update the above code hover effect, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: My problem is really about the 'background-position' (the hover work well so I didn't put it inside my post because there is already a lot of information). 

Hassan gives a way to go around the problem and it's work. So I will accept his answer but I would prefer to understand why the background position didn't work on IE ... sometimes.